# use gnu screen when ssh'ed as a user, but su as another

Tags: gnu-screen, su

Below is what happens when trying to use gnu screen. Essentially, it all works fine until I su as another user. then I get a `Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/7' - please check.` error

```
l413:~$ ssh sbird@example.com
sbird@example.com password: 
sbird@example:~$ screen
[screen is terminating]
sbird@example:~$ su - gradplan
Password: 
gradplan@example:~$ screen 
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/7' - please check.
gradplan@example:~$
```

How can I login as sbird, su to gradplan, and still use screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question:

`ssh sbird@example.com su grandplan -c “script /dev/null -qc \"screen\""`

Don't change the permissions on your /dev/pts/X - it just introduces an unnecessary security hole.

Answer (score 11):

Type `script /dev/null` before starting `screen`.

```
$ su - gradplan
$ screen
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/15' - please check.
$ script /dev/null
Script started, file is /dev/null
$ screen
# do whatever inside the screen
[detached]
$
```

ref: [ServerFault: Why does redirecting 'script' to /dev/null/ allow 'screen' to work while su'ed as another user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/255521/why-does-redirecting-script-to-dev-null-allow-screen-to-work-while-sued-as)

Comment: For future readers, I have found su'ing inside screen to actually be better practice, but since this answers what I actually asked better, I accepted this as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you:

```
ls -l /dev/pts/7
```

You will see it is owned by sbird, when you switch to gradplan, he doesn't have perms to touch that device.

You can try doing

```
chmod a+rw /dev/pts/X
```

(X being which pts # you are currently connected to, because it will change) before you screen.

Or you can screen as sbird, then in each screen window su there.